# how to write a linux service to start a service on computer A after a service in computer B is up and running?(computer A and B are in same network)

Tags: linux, service, systemd

in my senario I have an linux service on computer that need to run after a service in computer B(computer A and B are in same network).how can I use system.d to do this job?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this scenario, the simplest solution is to write a bash script like bellow.
before that you should set `ssh-key` between 2 linux computer.

at first open a file.

```
   nano /usr/bin/script.sh
```

and Put the following line in it.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh root@computerA  'systemctl start YOURServicName'
```

now you need to run this bash Script as SystemD Service in  computer B.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shell Script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

for more info use [this](https://tecadmin.net/run-shell-script-as-systemd-service/) link.

Finally
You need to add this line in your B.service file:

```
After=A.service
```

I hope my explanation was useful.